# Oracle XML driver for 11g

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, driver

Is there an XML driver for 11g?
I only found the legit links for Oracle 10g and 9i [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/xmldb/downloads/index-100632.html).
Can I use the 10g xmlparserv2.jar in 11g without having any problems?

**Edit:** I got problems with the 10g xmlparserv2.jar. It started looking for new class. I saw a blog that the jar is not compatible with 11g database. My problem now is to look for users who have an Enterprise Edition of the 11g database and then lend me the jar the I wanted.

Comment: WHat do you mean by "XML Driver"?  There is no such thing.  XMLDB is part of the database.

Comment: The drivers or the jar files like ojdbc6.jar, xdb6.jar and the driver that I was looking for (xmlparserv2.jar) that perfectly suits for Oracle 11g database. The jar file that I've downloaded from the Oracle website is just for 10g. I've read a blog and says that 11g XDK or the jar files are pre-installed on Enterprise editions of the database, not in XE editions. I got the XE so that's my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download JDeveloper editor at Oracle then find the XDK folder. The xmlparserv2.jar is inside the folder.